# List all stores, code unauthorized, message Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided

Tags: uber-api

I have tried using the request https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/stores, with my Uber developer account's owner and developer accounts, but I get this error: 401 unauthorized, { "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.", "code": "unauthorized" }

My HTTP call is as follows:

POST https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/stores

Headers:

limit: 10
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_DEVELOPER_ACCOUNT

Please help with this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ntE.png)

Answer (score 0):

you've given a post request, but this is a get request
https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/references/api/v1/get-eats-stores

this is the request

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
'https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/stores?limit=10'
```

but the token you got isn't your bearer token, I'm not sure, though that could be your client secret, You can create your bearer token following the documentations from the Access Token section of your application page
[image: via auth code]
[image: via client credentials]